# Aldryn_newsblog custom publishing date format

Tags: django-cms

Article publishing date format is "Mon dd, yyyy" I'd like it to be "dd.mm.yyyy".
The code, that causes different format is here

```
{{ article.publishing_date|date }}
```

Comment: You should localise your project with a formats file so you can set defaults for things like this; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files

Comment: Thank a lot! can you post you comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should localise your project with a formats file so you can set defaults for things like this.

There is a setting to tell django where your formats live;

```
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = [
    'project.formats'
]
```

Docs for that are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#format-module-path

As an example, the above formats files lives in a path like `project/formats/en/formats.py` and contain the formats for that language;

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j, Y'
TIME_FORMAT = 'P'
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'N j, Y, P'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'F j'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y P'

FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 0  # Sunday

US_DATE_FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y'
UK_DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'

DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ','
NUMBER_GROUPING = 3
```

Docs on creating your own formats are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files

You can make use of the formats you define by importing `django.utils.formats.get_format` then doing `get_format('DECIMAL_SEPARATOR')` or...

```
input_format = get_format('US_DATE_FORMAT')
v = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    value, input_format
)
```